# Categories list using rss feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, categories

spent a lot of time for searching the solution to my task, but i'm unable to find it. So i have 2 sites, first is presenting the company and second is company blog, they are installed on different databases, so i need to get Newest posts, comments, ant categories from blog. Posts and comments are done by using RSS feeds, but the main problem is categories. How to get all the list of categories in the first site from second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this recipe, simply paste the following code anywhere on your theme. It will

output a list of your categories with a link to the category rss feed.

```
<?php wp_list_categories('feed_image=http://www.myblog.com/image.gif&feed=XML Feed&optioncount=1&children=0'); ?>
```

The two parameters used here are:

feed_image: The url of the image to display as a link to your feed.

feed: The feed format